# cocos2d 3.x CCButton set the sprite frame image distorted and callback/block not working

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I need to set the sprite frame of a button.

When I use the constructor it's working:

```
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"but.png"];
    CCButton *button = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"" spriteFrame:sprite.spriteFrame];
    [button setBlock:^(id sender){...}]
```

[image]

But when I need to set the sprite frame afterwards,

```
    CCButton *button = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@""];
    button.background.spriteFrame = sprite.spriteFrame;
```

or this

```
    [button setBackgroundSpriteFrame:sprite.spriteFrame forState:CCControlStateNormal];
```

both are not working, the result is a distorted image, and the callback function or block is not called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I had the same problem and found a solution. Just do it like this:

```
CCSpriteFrame *spriteFrame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"Icon-Small.png"];
button = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"" spriteFrame:spriteFrame];
```

Works like a charm!